# sql writing to a csv file not showing in Desktop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, csv

I have a sql stored procedure that creates a csv file. Here is the following procedure.

```
SET @query = 'select * from tableName123'
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " ' + @query + ' "  queryout "c:\linecode.csv" -T -c -t,'''
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

The code runs successfully, but I don't see linecode.csv in the Desktop. Is this an issue with the write permission or is there something wrong with what I did?

I am using sql server 2008, and c# to call the stored procedure.

Comment: Presumably you're looking on the server's desktop, yes?

Comment: yes and I also tried c:\folder_name\linecode.csv but it doesn't appear there either

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that "Desktop:\" will point to the desktop.

Have you tried a trusted location such as "C:\folder\myfile.csv"?

It is likely that it otherwise created a "Desktop:\linecode.csv" file somewhere. Can you look for "*linecode.csv" ?

Comment: I tried something like c:\folder_name\linecode.csv but it doesn't appear there

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SET @query = 'select * from tableName123'
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " ' + @query + ' " queryout "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\linecode.csv" -T -c -t,'''
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

This depends on your version of Windows defining the `USERPROFILE` environment variable, which is present in all modern versions of Windows. [You can read more about the `USERPROFILE` environment variable here.](http://environmentvariables.org/UserProfile)